# Pandas - Calculate expected frequency table

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

What would be the most efficient way to generate an expected frequency table? i.e. for each cell value compute the result of `(row total * column total) / (total sum)`

So that the final dataframe is:

```
data = [[2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5], [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array and broadcasting:

```
a = df.values
pd.DataFrame((a.sum(0)*a.sum(1)[:,None])/a.sum(),
             columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

output:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
1  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda ss:ss.map(lambda x:ss.sum()),axis=1)*df.sum()/df.sum().sum()


out：


     A    B    C    D
0  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
1  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you're doing. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33596574)